# C++ boost-asio-network in async callback, which one is better ? using lambda or boost::bind()

Tags: c++, lambda, boost-asio

C++ lambda made me confusing.

bind functions for async read.

```
template<typename T>
class connection
    : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<connection<T>>
    , boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    using err = boost::system::error_code;

protected:
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;
...

// completion function
// read until meet '\n'
size_t on_read_completion(const err& error, size_t bytes) 
{
    if (error) { return 0; }

    bool found = std::find(read_buffer_, read_buffer_ + bytes, '\n') < read_buffer_ + bytes;
    return found ? 0 : 1;
}

// read message
void on_read(const err& error, size_t bytes)
{
    if (!started_) { return; }

    if (error)
    {
        std::cout << "[ERROR] async_read " << error.message();
        stop();
    }

    std::string msg(read_buffer_, bytes);
    // handle received message
    on_message(msg);
}
```

This is async read() function.

```
void read()
{
    if (!socket_.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "[ERROR] socket_ is not open\n";
        return;
    }

    std::fill_n(read_buffer_, MAX_MSG, '\0');

    // it works
#if 0
    async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(read_buffer_),
        boost::bind(&connection::on_read_completion, this->shared_from_this(), _1, _2),
        boost::bind(&connection::on_read, this->shared_from_this(), _1, _2));
#else // not works
    async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(read_buffer_),
        [this](const err& error, size_t bytes)->size_t
        {
            if (error) { return 0; }
            bool found = std::find(read_buffer_, read_buffer_ + bytes, '\n') < read_buffer_ + bytes;                return found ? 0 : 1;
        },
        [this](const err& error, size_t bytes)->void
        {
            if (!started_) { return; }
            if (error)
            {
                std::cout << "[ERROR] async_read\n" << error.message();
                return;
            }

            std::string msg(read_buffer_, bytes);
            on_message(msg);
        });
#endif
    }
```

The problem is lambda [capture] that is not containing shared_ptr itself. So when it call on_read_completion(), lambda capture this is not pointing shared_from_this() that I want.

I need a wise advice for this. Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already figured out that `this` needs to be explicitly captured in addition to the shared pointer, the latter just for the lifetime guarantee.

However your original question is slightly more interesting than you knew! There's a subtle difference between lambda and `bind` expressions. If you use `bind` to bind to a generic handler, it may preserve `asio_handler_invoke` (or more modern `get_associated_executor`) semantics under the ADL rule.

This is rarely a concern at the end-user level, but if you mean to provide a generic library of composable operations you may care about this kind of detail for failing to preserve the invocation semantics could lead to bugs (e.g. when a composed handler is bound to a strand executor).

> As a sidenote, in the case you showed, consider using the overload of `async_read_until` that take a string(view) or regex.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I found the what is the problem.

```
...
async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(read_buffer_),
  [this](const err& error, size_t bytes)->size_t
  {
    if (error) { return 0; }
    bool found = std::find(read_buffer_, read_buffer_ + bytes, '\n') < read_buffer_ + bytes;
    return found ? 0 : 1;
  },
  [this, self = std::move(this->shared_from_this())](const err& error, size_t bytes)->void
  {
    if (!started_) { return; }
    if (error)
    {
      std::cout << "[ERROR] async_read\n" << error.message() << "\n";
      return;
    }
    std::string msg(read_buffer_, bytes);
    self->on_message(msg);
});

...
```

it worked!

But if you have tips for this please comment! Thank you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Explicitly moving from the `shared_from_this()` is not useful.